# Link to shell script does not run from a different location

Tags: 12.04, shortcuts, scripts, symbolic-link

I have an application created using Lazarus. I can run it from the terminal like this:

```
./myapp para
```

Now this file is currently in a home folder. So I created a shell script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /home/khalid/Home/laz-proj-linux
./myapp para
```

When I run the shell script from the current folder (nautilus) it works.
When I create a link to it in the same folder, it works.

But When I drag that link to the desktop, it does not work.

Am I missing something? Please advise.

Thanks!

Comment: how do you create the link? if the path is correct it should work this way..... (/home/khalid/Home/laz-proj-linux looks strange...)

Comment: I right-clicked the shell file and took "Make link" from the menu

Comment: hmmm, is the path correct? please post the output of: ls -lah /home/khalid/Home/laz-proj-linux/ and the directory listing of your desktop ( ls -lah /home/khalid/Desktop/ (i think "Desktop" is the name for it... place the right directory where the "link" should be placed)

Comment: @WolfgangVogl Please give me your comment as an answer. It really helped solve my problem. I had misunderstood the path. You command helped see that the path was invalid. Apparently the path should have been `/home/khalid/laz-proj-linux/' wihtout *Home" in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hmmm, is the path correct? please post the output of:

```
ls -lah /home/khalid/Home/laz-proj-linux/
```

and the directory listing of your desktop `ls -lah /home/khalid/Desktop/` (I think "Desktop" is the name for it... place the right directory where the "link" should be placed)